# String Index Out of Range Error: How to Fix?

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

I am trying to mix up a string using string buffers. The program should randomly select a character within the word that is in StringBuffer1 (sb1). Append it to the empty StringBuffer2 (sb2), and continuously do this until the `sb1.length()` of the StringBuffer1 (sb1) is equal to 0 (empty).

Here is my code:

```
String word = "Hello";
String empty = "";
StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer(word);
StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer(empty);
Random randomChar = new Random();

while (word.length() != 0) {
    int charIndex = randomChar.nextInt(word.length());
    char character = sb1.charAt(charIndex);
    sb2.append(character);
    sb1.deleteCharAt(charIndex);
}

System.out.println(word.length());
System.out.println(word);
System.out.println(sb2);
```

Comment: Read your code again more carefully. You're looping on `word.length()`, but you're deleting from `sb1`. This would be a great time to learn to use a debugger, which would have allowed you to figure this out yourself in less time than it took you to post here.

Comment: Why not convert to a char array, then shuffle it, and convert back to a string?

Answer (score 0):

You are  making changes in `StringBuffer sb1` whereas you are validating the loop against length of `String word`. So.

1. You are creating an infinite loop, and
2. `Random` number is generated based on `word.length()`, which will be 5 always.

**Use `sb1.length()` instead of `word.length()`** so that length of `sb1` is used for loop as well as random number.

Comment: Just providing replacement code without explaining what you fixed is a poor answer.

Comment: I though that answer was sufficient to understand the problem..but edited the answer for explanation

Answer (score -1):

Try this. There might be possibility that this may loop more times than expected because of Random.

**Explanation :** Issue was with the index. When you are selecting random from word length you will get element from 0 -> length-1 but at the same time you are removing element from string buffer as well so next time when you will get index=length-1 it won't be present in string buffer that's why you are getting error. Also I have added terminated condition when string buffer length becomes zero.

```
            String word = "Hello";
            String empty = "";
            StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer(word);
            StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer(empty);
            Random randomChar = new Random();

            while (word.length() != 0 && sb1.length() != 0) {
                int charIndex = randomChar.nextInt(word.length());
                if (sb1.length() > charIndex) {
                    char character = sb1.charAt(charIndex);
                    sb2.append(character);
                    sb1.deleteCharAt(charIndex);
                }
            }

            System.out.println(word.length());
            System.out.println(word);
            System.out.println(sb2);
```

Comment: Just providing replacement code without explaining what you fixed is a poor answer.

Comment: @John3136 Thank you for notifying. I have added explanation as well. I thought after watching code, the reporter will be able to identify what was the issue because change is not much.

Comment: @cody123 posting others comments on others answer..not a good practice. Anyways..modified the explanation as you pointed out.